# gRPC is not working as expected in lamda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, grpc

I have grpc server and client implemented in nodejs. Server is running on `0.0.0.0:8080`. Client can connect just fine when I test in local.
But when I move client to aws-lambda function and invoke locally it does not work. Server does not get any request.
Any idea what might be the problem?

I have tried changing ports and turning off firewall. Still no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the `server.js`

```
const grpc = require('grpc');
const path = require('path');

const FILE_PATH = './schema.proto';
const PROTO_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, FILE_PATH);
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
const tourProcess = require('../../src/modules/tour/src/controllers/internal/v100');

const server = new grpc.Server();
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, {
  keepCase: true,
  longs: String,
  enums: String,
  arrays: true,
  oneofs: true
});


const pivoTourProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).grpcPivoTour;
server.addService(pivoTourProto.pivoTourService.service, {
  getTours: tourProcess.getTours
});

server.bind('0.0.0.0:8080', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
console.log('GRPC running at 127.0.0.1:8080');
module.exports = server;
```

```
client.js

var path = require('path');
const FILE_PATH = "./schema.proto";
const PROTO_PATH = path.resolve( __dirname, FILE_PATH );
const grpc = require("grpc");
const protoLoader = require("@grpc/proto-loader");

var packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, {
  keepCase: true,
  longs: String,
  enums: String,
  arrays: true
});

const pivoTourProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).grpcPivoTour;
const client = new pivoTourProto.pivoTourService(
    '0.0.0.0:8080',
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
);

module.exports = client;
```

```
//LAMBDA HANDLER lambda.js


require('dotenv').config();
const client = require('./src/grpc/client');

module.exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    tourId = "1";
    const req = {"id": tourId};

    client.getTours(req, function(error, tour){
        if(error){
        console.log(error);
        }else{
        console.log(tour);
        }
    
    });

};
```

Comment: Is the client deployed in aws lambda trying to connect to server running locally in your machine? That won't work. You would have to deploy the server to an EC2 instance and then try to connect from aws lambda.

Comment: @MjZac lambda function in local pc, not deployed yet to aws. is that still cannot connect?

Comment: I think the problem is your port. Lambdas do not expose port 8080. So whatever you use to test your Lambda locally, probably does not export it as well. It should be run on port 80.

Comment: This is not an AWS Lambda problem. Any client anywhere will not be able to connect to your local server. Your code is trying to connect to 0.0.0.0 which only works if the client and server are running in the same machine.